# Need a way to activate events from h:selectManyCheckbox even if disabled="true"

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a h:selectManyCheckbox as part of a p:dataTable - to avoid user selecting the row I set a onclick event to return false - this works fine. However, I also need to load some server side data via AJAX once the event goes through and it appears there is no way to do this.

Has anyone had a similar experience and can perhaps share some ideas.

Any tips would be helpful.

Thanks

Tried to post a code snippet but keep on getting an error via stack over flow.

Comment: So you've got a selectable table and apart from that a `h:selectManyCheckbox` on each row? Which event are you dealing with (the one with Ajax)?

Comment: Yes I need to send an AJAX event - tried with the AJAX control but appears that it doesn't fire.

Comment: I tried attaching an AJAX event just to make sure and it causes the check box to become select able which isn't the behavior we're looking for - is there any workaround for this ? Thanks.

Comment: I can't see the point of having a disabled `h:selectManyCheckBox` listening to ajax events. The tag events which could fire ajax are `blur, change, click, dblclick, focus, keydown, keypress, keyup, mousedown, mousemove, mouseout, mouseover, mouseup, select, valueChange`, none of them can happen when component is disabled.